# Min-width, Max-Width Media Queries not working with XML?

Tags: css, xml, media-queries

I have a very simple XML Document like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>                                                                                   
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<root>
  <Elemone>
    test
  </Elemone>
</root>
```

I am trying to use responsive media queries in the css like this:

```css
@media (max-width: 900px) {                                                                                                                                                                               
    root {                                                                                                                                                                                              
        background-color: red;                                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                                                                         
@media (min-width: 901px) {                                                                                                                                                                               
    root {                                                                                                                                                                                              
        background-color: yellow;                                                                                                                                                                         
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

But, even when using an iPhone, only the `min-width` properties are shown. I have tried using `px` and `em` units, and neither work.